# Import C++ member function at run-time with Gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

### Problem

I am currently working on a plugin-library, where one should be able to not only import C-Linkage symbols, but all imported things.

Thus far it works, though the problem is, that gcc screws member-function calls up.

If I export the following:

```
static member_function(Class* c)
{ c->method();}
```

it works fine an I can access the class-members. But if I do the following:

```
void (Class ::*p)() = import("Class::method");
(x.*p)();
```

i get the right pointer and also am able to call the function and the passed arguments, but the this pointer is pointing into nirvana. I think gcc is taking it from the wrong position of the stack or something like that.

It works just fine with MSVC.

I am using mingw-w64 5.1.

Does anyone have an idea what the error could be?

### Simple example:

#### plugin.cpp

```
#include <iostream>    

namespace space {
class __declspec(dllexport) SomeExportThingy
{
    int i = 42;
  public:
    virtual void __declspec(dllexport) Method(int*) const
    {
         using namespace std;
         cout << "Calling Method" << endl;
         cout << pi << endl;
         cout << *pi << endl;
         cout << this << endl;
         cout << this->i << endl;
    }
}
}
```

#### loader.cpp

```
namespace space {
class SomeExportThingy
{
///dummy to have some data in the address
    int dummy[20];
};

int main()
{
    auto h = LoadLibrary("plugin.dll");
    auto p = GetProcAddress(h, "_ZNK5space16SomeExportThingy6MethodEPi");

    typedef void (space::SomeExportThingy::*mptr)(int*) const;

    ///used because posix passed void*
    auto fp = *reinterpret_cast<mptr*>(&p);

    space::SomeExportThingy st;
    int value = 22;

    cout << "ValueLoc: " << &value << endl;
    cout << "StLoc: " << &st << endl;


    (st.*fp)(&value);

}
```

### Results

Now what happens is, that the function is called and the pointer to pi is passed correctly. However, the this pointer is completly screwed up.
Again: it works with MSVC, which get's the this pointer correctly, but gcc get's this wrong.
I have no idea why this happens, and removing the virtual from the method doesn't change that either.
I have no idea what causes this, so maybe someone has an idea what the ABI is doing here.

Here are the pointers I am getting:

- 0x00400000 == GetModuleHandleA(NULL)
- 0x61840000 == GetModuleHandleA("plugin.dll")
- 0x0029fcc4 == _&st
- 0x00ddcd60 == this

I wasn't able to find any relation between the values

Comment: Not sure,  but did you try calling `import()` with the mangled function name?

Comment: could be due to name-mangling...general use would be, mark a free standing function as extern, which prevents it from name-mangling...use that for retreiving an object and then you can acess it's member functions...

Comment: Marking a function as simply `extern` alone isn't sufficient to prevent name mangling, @basav; it has to be marked as `extern "C"`.

Comment: If you are trying to import methods compiled by MSVC into a GCC (g++) compiled application, then you __must__ do so via an `extern "C"` interface. The name mangling algorithms are __intentionally different__ between different C++ compilers, because generated code may have differing (undocumented, and mutually incompatible) internal structure.

Comment: What do you mean by Mingw (correctly capitalized as MinGW) 5.1?  The only MinGW-5.1 ever published by MinGW.org, (who own the MinGW trademark, in any capitalization) was a (now antique) GCC-3.x based integrated package. I'm guessing you don't mean that, in which case this is __not__ a MinGW question; maybe `mingw-w64`, which is a different product, not associated in any way with MinGW.org, (and technically infringing the MinGW trademark). Please clarify, and/or tag appropriately.

Comment: i missed that part..thanks for correction..that should be extern "C"..

Comment: Well no, I import the function by it's mangled name, and it is called. If I do not use the this pointer but other arguments it works fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is my import function, it generates the mangled name. The function loading works.

Comment: Calling by mangled name suggests that you may be attempting to subvert the very intent of differing compilers mangling differently; this difference is to protect you from inadvertently calling a method with an utterly different and incompatible ABI organization. If this really is the case, then it should come as no surprise if it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: But I am using the same compiler, which has the same ABI. So yeah, it came as a surprise.

Comment: "_But I am using the same compiler, which has the same ABI_". Then you need to provide a MCVE /SSCCE to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, it seems the this pointer is modified.
I consistently get: this = &st + GetModuleHandleA("plugin.dll")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not going to work with GCC:

```
typedef void (space::SomeExportThingy::*mptr)(int*) const;

///used because posix passed void*
auto fp = *reinterpret_cast<mptr*>(&p);
```

The representation of a pointer-to-member is twice the size of a normal function pointer (or a `void*`) so you are reading two words from a memory location that only contains one word. The second word (which tells the compiler how to adjust the `this` pointer for the call) is garbage, it is just whatever happens to be after `p` on the stack.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html:

> In C++, pointer to member functions (PMFs) are implemented using a wide pointer of sorts to handle all the possible call mechanisms; the PMF needs to store information about how to adjust the ‘this’ pointer,

- `p` is a `void*` so it's a memory location on the stack that occupies `sizeof(void*)` bytes.
- `&p` is a pointer to that memory location.
- `reinterpret_cast<mptr*>(&p)` is a pointer to `2*sizeof(void*)` bytes at the same address.
- `*reinterpret_cast<mptr*>(&p)` reads `2*sizeof(void*)` bytes from a memory location that is only `sizeof(void*)` bytes in size.
- Bad things happen.

Comment: You are amazing sir! That was the problem and it works (for non-virtual calls) if I put a nullptr into the second part.

Answer (score 1):

For linux, the functions for dynamic function loading are: dlopen(), dlsym(), and dlclose().  Please reference: [dlopen() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).

Consider that C++ method names are 'mangled' and and they have an invisible '*this' parameter passed before all the others. Together both issues makes trying to directly access C++ objects not trivial when using dynamic linking.

The easiest solution I've found is to use 'C' function(s) that expose access to the C++ object instance.

Secondly, memory management of C++ objects is not trivial when the code to instantiate is within an .so library object, though the referencing code is from the user's app.

For the long answer as to why avoiding Pointer to C++ Member Methods is difficult, please reference: [ISO CPP Reference, Pointers to Methods](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

---

```
/** File: MyClass.h **/

// Explicitly ensure 'MyClassLoaderFunc' is NOT name mangled.
extern 'C' MyClass* MyClassLoaderFunc(p1, p2 ,p3, etc );
extern 'C' MyClass* MyClassDestroyerFunc(MyClass* p);

// Create function pointer typedef named 'LoaderFuncPtr'
typedef MyClass*(MyClassLoaderFunc* LoaderFuncPtr)(p1,p2,p3,etc);

// Define MyClass
class MyClass
{  
   /** methods & members for the class go here **/      
   char dummy[25];
   int method( const char *data);
};
```

---

```
/** File: MyClass.cpp **/
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass* MyLoaderFunc(p1, p2 ,p3, etc) {
    MyClass* newInstance = new MyClass::CreateInstance( p1, p2, p3, etc);
    /** Do something with newInstance **/
    return newInstance;
}

MyClass::method(const char* data)
{
}
```

---

```
/** File: MyProgram.cpp **/
#include "MyClass.h"
main()
{
    // Dynamically load in the library containing the object's code.
    void *myClassLibrary = dlopen("path/to/MyClass.so",RTLD_LOCAL);

    // Dynamically resolve the unmangled 'C' function name that 
    // provides the bootstrap access to the MyClass*
    LoaderFuncPtr loaderPtr = dlsym(myClassLibrary,"MyClassLoaderFunc");
    DestroyFuncPtr destroyerPtr = dlsym(myClassLibrary,"MyClassDestroyerFunc");

    // Use dynamic function to retrieve an instance of MyClass.
    MyClass* myClassPtr = loadPtr(p1,p2,p3,etc);

    // Do something with MyClass
    myClassPtr->method();

    // Cleanup of object should happen within original .cpp file
    destroyPtr(myClassPtr);
    myClassPtr = NULL;

    // Release resources
    dlclose(myClassLibrary);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps..

I also suggest a factory paradigm as an more robust solution, that I'll leave to the reader to explore.

Comment: could you return a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` from the `MyClassLoaderFunc()` (and avoid the `MyClassDestroyerFunc()`) or is this not allowed/possible/supported/portable with `extern "C"` linkage?

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan pointed out, pointer-to-members are bigger than normal function pointers.
The simplest solution is to reserve and initialize the extra space.

```
typedef void (space::SomeExportThingy::*mptr)(int*) const;

union {
  mptr fp;
  struct {
    FARPROC function;
    size_t offset;
  };
} combFp;
combFp.function = p;
combFp.offset = 0;

auto fp = combFp.fp;
```